# Passing TCL keylist as a parameter to a function changes its type

Tags: tcl

I am trying to pass a Tcl Keylist to a function and when I access the variable in the function, its type is not a keylist. Package used to get key lists is TclX.

Sample Code:

```
keylset x port1.port "1/1"
keylset x port1.stream "1"
# keylkeys x works at this point

keylset y port1.port "1/1"
keylset y port2.port "1/2"
keylset y port1.stream "1"
# keylkeys y works at this point

# Following call returns error: the error is keyed list entry must be a valid, 2 element list, got "port1"
proc_name $x

# Following call is successful
proc_name $y

# procedure is part of a package and the package is sourced at the start of the script
proc proc_name {x} {
    # puts x for one port input ->  port1 {{port 1/1} {stream 1}}
    # puts y for one port input -> { {port1 {{port 1/1} {stream 1}}} {port2 {port 1/1}} }
    puts [keylkeys x]
}
```

I am not sure why the keylist is not recognized when passed to the procedure

Comment: 'keylset' is not a standard part of Tcl. You should include what extension is providing that command as part of your question. Assuming they are not just procedures defined in your code.

Comment: I am using TclX, edited the question to include information.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't have a tcl with tclx to test with, but</strike> you <strike>probably</strike> need to pass the list variable *name* to the proc and then use `upvar` inside. Try this:

```
keylset x ...
keylset y ...

proc_name x      ;# just the varname
proc_name y      ;# just the varname

proc proc_name {varname} {
    upvar 1 $varname keyedlist
    puts [keylkeys keyedlist]
}
```

Comment: your solution worked for the example of provided but didnt in the actual script. In the script, the procedure is part of a package which is sourced at the start of the script, do you think that could have an impact? I am adding the answer that solved the problem

Comment: Yes, my answer depended on you being able to add the `upvar` command into the proc. If it's out of your control, then you'll have to treat the keyed list as a plain list.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem is someone else has the same issue in future (credit goes to one of my awesome colleagues):

As the print inside the procedure shows that one set of `{}` are missing, I added an extra set of `""` before the function call.

```
# please refer to the code in the question section, I am just adding the changed snippet here
proc_name \"$x\" ;# solved the problem inside the procedure
```

Comment: `proc_name [list $x]` would be better.